# Scalaz automatic typeclass resolution

Tags: scala, functional-programming, typeclass, scalaz

I have several `Map[String, String]` and want to merge them so values remain the same. By default Map semigroup will concatenate strings, so I'm using `Tags.LastVal`.
Currently I'm doing following:

```
m1.mapValues(Tags.LastVal) |+| m2.mapValues(Tags.LastVal)
```

This mapping looks verbose and tedious.
Can I somehow tell compiler to use specific Semigroup in the scope, like `Semigroup[Map[K, V @@ LastVal]` rather than default one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make the instance you want implicit in the scope you need and it'll be found by the compiler:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def mergeWithReplace(m1: Map[String, String], m2: Map[String, String]) = {
  implicit val stringInstance: Semigroup[String] = Semigroup.lastSemigroup
  m1 |+| m2
}
```

And then:

```
scala> mergeWithReplace(Map("a" -> "foo", "b" -> "qux"), Map("a" -> "bar"))
res0: Map[String,String] = Map(a -> bar, b -> qux)
```

Even apart from theoretical arguments for coherence, though, this is annoying and fragile. For example, the name of the implicit must be `stringInstance` in order to shadow the implicit that was imported from `scalaz.std.string`, since that one has a more specific type, even though you're not asking for a more specific type. I don't remember whether there's some excuse for that precedence behavior, and I don't really want to have to care, so I tend to avoid using local instances like that.

In this case there happens to be a nicer solution, though. Scalaz provides `Plus` instances for maps, and `Plus` doesn't know about the value type, so it combines values by picking the last one. This means you can get what you want by using the `<+>` operator from `Plus`:

```
def mergeWithReplace(m1: Map[String, String], m2: Map[String, String]) =
  m1 <+> m2
```

And then:

```
scala> mergeWithReplace(Map("a" -> "foo", "b" -> "qux"), Map("a" -> "bar"))
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> bar, b -> qux)
```

You're not usually going to get that lucky, though.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't know about Plus.

Comment: Hey @TravisBrown. It seems there's no instance of `Plus` for Maps in scalaz. `mergeWithReplace` results in error on 7.0.6 and 7.1.6.

Comment: @chuwy Oh, I didn't remember when it got introduced. It's definitely available in 7.2.0.

Comment: It's defined for `Map` via `IsEmpty` in 7.1.6 and Should work.